# Found no calls to: 'R_registerRoutines', 'R_useDynamicSymbols' unresolved

Tags: r, rcpp

I've been strangling with an unresolved `'R_registerRoutines', 'R_useDynamicSymbols'` note from R CMD check. I have read the relevant Section in the 'Writing R Extensions' and also checked various other posts online but the problem persists.

Summary of what I have done:

1. I created the `init.c` file put in the `src/` directory with the following content given in [1] below. This was done using `tools::package_native_routine_registration_skeleton(".", "src/init.c", character_only = FALSE)` (because with the default `character_only = TRUE` was not working).
2. I checked if the same names appear in `RcppExports.cpp` in `src/` and `RcppExports.R` in `R/` given in [2] below.
3. I have added `useDynLib(JMbayes, .registration = TRUE)` in the NAMESPACE.

Hence, any pointers would be welcome!

[[1] init.c](http://www.drizopoulos.com/Rpgm/JMbayes_init.c)

[[2] RcppExports.cpp](http://www.drizopoulos.com/Rpgm/RcppExports.cpp)

Comment: I have a feeling you tested this on a Windows machine inside RStudio with `devtools`. If so, you will likely get a false alert. You should consider running it on win builder offered by CRAN. Furthermore, this "glue" is auto created by _Rcpp_ as of 0.12.12. So, no need to construct your own `src/init.c` anymore.

Comment: I have the same issue on Windows. But if you test on win-builder, you won't see this NOTE. And CRAN also, so don't care too much about it.

Comment: Yes indeed, this is on Windows with Rstudio and `devtools`. Thanks for the pointer that this is probably a false alert. I'll also try it on the win-builder.

Comment: Just don't use `devtools`.  Use `R CMD ...`.

Answer (score 4):

Promoting my comment to an answer.

The reason for the error is due to an interaction between RStudio and `devtools` on a Windows machine. Thus, what you are encountering is a *false* positive on the Registration of Native Entry points. If you submit your package to be checked on either [`r-hub.io`](https://builder.r-hub.io/) or [`winbuilder`](https://win-builder.r-project.org/) you should receive the appropriately response.

Furthermore, the Registration of Native Entry points provided by `tools:: package_native_routine_registration_skeleton()` is now done automatically in  Rcpp as of 0.12.12. Thus, there is no need to supply your own `src/init.c`. However, to engage this autocreation behavior, you must delete the `src/init.c` file and re-run `Rcpp::compileAttributes()`. This will lead to `RcppExports.cpp` being generated with the native registration registered at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

In general, this will just work automatically:  with (current) Rcpp (versions 0.12.12, or at least 0.12.11) these registrations are being created / added when `compileAttributes()` runs.

Which RStudio's build feature runs for you.  One issue we are aware of is that the switch to symbols with underscores (needed to differentiate from R symbols) leads to one round of double symbols *so you may need to run `compileAttributes()` twice*.

See other questions here and on the GitHub issue tickets, it has been discussed quite a bit by now.

*Edit*: With the code in [this JMbayes repo](https://github.com/drizopoulos/JMbayes) I cannot reproduce the issue. It runs fine for me with no warnings about missing registrations.  Did you fix it by now?

Comment: No, I didn't do any fix, but from the comment above it seems to be a false alert in my machine. Thanks!

Comment: Just don't use `devtools`.  Use `R CMD ...`.  I bet what you encounter is reproducible, but you may need to the good folks bringing you `devtools`.  Rcpp does its thing just fine.